# Probability of RGB cube with identically coloured opposite faces?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I was given a really interesting problem at an interview. It seems like an elementary question but I just can’t think about it it properly. Apologies if the wording is a bit odd, I can’t think of better ways the phrase the question:

> The six faces of a cube can be painted red, green or blue. What is the probability that each pair of opposite faces is coloured a distinct colour (i.e. one pair opposite faces is painted red, another pair painted green, the last pair painted blue) if:
>   a) the colour for each face is randomly chosen with probability $\frac13$?
>   b) the cube has exactly 2 red, 2 green, and 2 blue faces?

I am not too sure how to begin because of the geometry/symmetry involved. For example, for a), is the probability of a fully red cube $\frac1{3^6}$ or $\frac6{3^6}$? In fact, is the number of ways to have three pairs of identically coloured opposite faces of distinct colours $3!$, or is there more geometry involved? I feel like I’m overthinking somewhere.

Tldr; how do I account for overcounting due to the symmetry in the problem? Am I even overcounting in the first place?

Comment: When you say "each pair of opposite faces is coloured a distinct colour" does that mean the two sides *in each pair* have the same colour - so there is a pair of red sides, a pair of green sides and a pair of blue side ? Or does it mean the two sides in each pair of opposite sides have different colours ?

Comment: @gandalf61 the former!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that these faces are on a cube is irrelevant for the problem. The only thing that matters is, you have 3 pairs of faces to paint.

(a) There are $3^6 = 729$ ways to paint the cube. There are $3!$ ways to assign the colors to the three pairs. Therefore the probability is $\frac{6}{729} = \frac{2}{243}$.

(b) Now there are only ${6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 2} = 90$ ways to paint the cube. Therefore the answer to (b) is $\frac{6}{90} = \frac{1}{15}$.

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit more on why the geometry is irrelevant?

Comment: @user107224 Because you could just peel off the faces and put them on the table. The problem would remain the same, right?

Comment: wow didn’t think of it that way! Spent so long dividing things by 6 and 2 that I lost track of everything! Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on the probability space. If one understands the second question as “probability of every possible cube is the same”, then geometry plays role, and the answer is 1/6